# Double click listener on eclipse workspace resource

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I want to open a dialog when user double clicks on certain file types(ex: .pc,.mn etc) in Project Explorer.

I don't know whether this is the correct way to do it or not. I have created a dummy editor(by extending org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextEditor) for these file types and in the init method, I have created the dialog and opened it.

But after user closes the dialog (by pressing OK or Cancel button). Editor is opened with an error as shown below.
[image]

My code in init method

```java
@Override
public void init(IEditorSite site, IEditorInput input) throws PartInitException {

    FileEditorInput fileEdi = null;
    if (input instanceof FileEditorInput) {
        fileEdi = (FileEditorInput)input;
    }
    ABCTitleAreaDialog dia = new ABCTitleAreaDialog(site.getShell(), fileEdi.getFile().getLocation().toString(),
            null);
    dia.setHelpAvailable(false);
    if (Window.OK == dia.open()) {
        Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Code to open Perspective
            }
        });
    }
    IWorkbenchPart part = site.getPart();
    if (PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().closeEditor((IEditorPart)part, false)) {
        System.out.println("closed the editor");
    }
    throw new PartInitException("Error opening editor"));//$NON-NLS-1$
}
```

Is it possible to Cancel/Abort the editor creation process, so that I can avoid opening the error editor part.

Any alternative solution are also OK for me.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than throw the `PartInitException` you could use `asyncExec` to close the editor:

```java
@Override
public void init(final IEditorSite site, final IEditorInput input)
{
  setSite(site);
  setInput(input);

  Display.getCurrent().asyncExec(new Runnable()
  {
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
      site.getPage().closeEditor(Editor.this, false);
    }
  });
}
```

Edit: Changed to show full init method

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK Worked for me. What happens?

Comment: Error Editor is opened again with the message :"Editor initialization failed: <Editor_Id>.  Site is incorrect."

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK You will have to do enough of the normal editor initialization to keep the editor system happy.

Comment: After I called  setSite(site);setInput(fileEdi); I am not getting error editor but getting exceptions like.=='org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor' from bundle '278'
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument not valid
==!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt".
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed ===.Is there a way to abort the editor creation flow in init method itself?Tried throwing PartInitException but not working.Is it possible to avoid these exceptions

Comment: Changed code to show the full `init` method. This runs without errors for me. The errors you are getting may be because you are using things that have been disposed in your other `asyncExec` `Runnable`.

Comment: Yes its working,by using your code am not getting any exceptions but the file opens quickly and shows the contents of the file for a fraction of second and closes immediately,so user feels something wrong happened.Is it possible to avoid this

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing the following calls at the beginning of your init(...)-method:

```
super.setInput(input);
super.setSite(site);
```

---

Enhancement:

You should consider using retargetable actions via the extension points **org.eclipse.ui.navigator.navigatorContent** and **org.eclipse.ui.navigator.viewer** to contribute a new ResourceContent to **org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer**.
Thus you could call an Action which opens your dialog and the editor depending on the dialog's exit status

Further reading see

- [Eclipse Help for Kepler: The Common Navigator Framework](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/cnf.htm)
- [Building a Common Navigator based viewer](http://scribbledideas.blogspot.de/2006/06/building-common-navigator-_115067357450703178.html)